# Extracting names from a list of edge betweeness values

Tags: r, igraph

I am analyzing a brain network in iGrahph that is both unweighted and undirected. I used the function `edge.betweeness()` to calculate the edge betweeness values of every edge in the graph.

My question is two-fold. One, is there a way to return/order these values from largest to smallest. Second, and more importantly, is there a way to return the IDs of the shortest paths (the input and target fields) for a particular edge of a ?

Here is an example of my code and its output. 
    library(igraph)

```
g1 <- graph.adjacency(Mdata, mode = "undirected", weighted = NULL) 
EBall <-edge.betweenness(g1) 
EBall
```

And here is an example of the output

```
 [1]  2.049215  2.556322  2.866237  3.019527  2.967279  2.457281  3.074174  3.375743  6.537080  3.814843
 [11]  2.431858  2.312276  1.859894  3.054581  3.490107  3.411886  3.679377  1.928778  3.291615  2.533857
 [21]  2.918107  3.936021  3.256922  2.699181  3.172758  1.417157  3.722341  9.874517  3.760476  2.004167
 [31]  2.515482  4.083514  2.994023  3.769305  3.770671  8.283061  2.061248  3.995807  1.941667  2.147180
 [41]  4.222169  4.597613  4.334425  5.083550  2.344623  4.220540  2.432449  3.366699  3.328510  3.599603
 [51]  4.193479  1.622300  3.045646  2.259679  1.852987  1.897630  1.505866  3.236519  2.177356  6.084460
 [61]  1.693265  5.258131  1.971043  2.952772  2.589261  5.056219  4.019826  1.963931  2.356110  2.489709
 [71]  1.921604  1.875547  4.734674  1.935493  2.174057  3.628204  3.189276  7.687193  4.836767 11.711006
 [81]  4.206202  2.234419  2.613591  4.569120  3.293229  2.996686  3.780195  5.679092  2.203373  2.652249
 [91]  2.211601  2.426279  5.137883  5.585201  5.184921  5.794300  2.691625  5.151708  2.412702  3.217096
[101]  3.650093  2.742779  5.409474  9.603414  8.630837  2.935926  3.435576  2.578690  2.766771  2.749769
```

These are the EB values for all the edges in the network. I would like them to be ranked by their values, and displayed next to their IDs for a particular edge. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: where are the `ID` 's

Comment: Here is an example of the IDs.
`> E(g1)`


`+ 387/387 edges (vertex names):
 [1] V1 --V2         V1 --V3         V1 --V3A        V1 --V4         V1 --V4t        V1 --MT        
 [7] V1 --MSTd.p     V1 --PO         V1 --LIP        V1 --PIP        V1 --DP         V1 --FST       
[13] V1 --TEO        V1 --TEad       V1 --TEam.a     V1 --TEam.p     V1 --TEav       V1 --TEpd `

Comment: you should expand your question into a reproducible example